# Как правильно cделать поиск mysql

Tags: mysql, поиск, like

Есть задача - контекстный поиск по ключевым словам в базе данных mysql. Нужно решение что-бы искать при любом совпадении внутри названия статьи.

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM articles a 
  WHERE $sql 
    AND (MATCH(a.title) 
AGAINST ({search}) 
     OR a.title LIKE '%слово%'
```

щас использую такое решение которое позволяет использовать полнотекстовый поиск, но проблема в том что не работает если например в базе есть - *Васяпупкин* а я введу в поиске  - *Васяпуп*

Comment: Я когда то такое решал. В итоге во первых все слова из всех текстов при записи в базу собирались и выносились в отдельную таблицу, буквально ID-слова, ID-записи где встречается. Во вторых на основании морфемного словаря я составил таблицу смены окончаний, которая вырезала возможный корень и добавляла все возможные окончания. Но это было лет 10 назад, сейчас думаю библиотеки должны быть готовые. посмотрим, что ответят знатоки. Если не ответят, могу дать словарь аффиксов, правда запросы к нему надо будет с sql оракла переводить

Comment: @Mike а нет проще решения? например регулярка на первые три символа, это бы облегчило задачу уже

Comment: Можно конечно что то в хвосте отрезать, поставить туда %. В конце концов сразу искать Васяпуп%, но это не решение проблемы. Не надо забывать про беглые гласные. И мутации некоторых гласных в корнях перед определенными окончаниями. Кто? "Заяц" О ком? "О Зайце" - что бы их найти тупым методом нужно искать За%, так что "Запорожец" - это то же разновидность зайца...

Comment: И запись у меня в таблице аффиксов для ситуации с зайцами выглядит примерно так: `{del=2, oend='яц', tmask='аеио', nend='йца'}`, Т.е. правило применения уже не простое, реагировать на окончание 'яц', перед которым одна из букв 'аеио'. И подобных записей у меня 1800, так что я бы не взялся выражать это регулярками

Comment: зачем изобретать велосипед, если есть готовые решения? например, [sphinxsearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/), который прекрасно справляется с поставленной задачей и делает это быстро

Comment: @BOPOH Вот поэтому я в первом каменте и написал, что надо подождать тех кто библиотеки готовые знает :) Когда я этим занимался библиотек еще не придумали

Comment: @Mike, это было автору сказано, не вам ) 10 лет назад мало что существовало, а если и было, то скорее всего ни сколько не лучше своих велосипедов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. LIKE "%text%" благодаря первому % вызывает полный скан всех строк, не используйте этого примерно никогда.
2. Красивый и прямой метод будет с использованием SphinxSearch, Apache Solr, Lucene, но это требует установки и настройки дополнительного софта на сервер (зато оно того реально стоит)
3. Доведите запрос до вида:

```
    SELECT * 
       FROM articles a 
      WHERE $sql 
        AND (
        MATCH(a.title) AGAINST ({search} IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        )
```

И рядом с формой поиска допишите краткую [инструкцию](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html):
"слово" - просто искать
"+слово" - обязательно включать
"-слово" - обязательно не включать
"слов*" - частичный поиск